# Add "Connection: close" to response headers in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, header, connection

I am working in a ASP.NET MVC 5 project that needs to add a "Connection: close" response header to a certain request. I Tried to add the conventional way:

```
Response.AddHeader("Connection", "close");
```

But the header is removed from the response, not being present in the Chrome network tab.
How do I add this header to a response?